# XSLT 1.0 Format Time

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0 and I have a time value stored as an integer in military time and I need to output it into standard time. For example, a value would be 1400 and I need to output it to 2:00 PM. Can this be achieved in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's more than just formatting. You also want to convert 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation.

Given an input of:

**XML**

```
<input>1435</input>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:variable name="h" select="input div 100"/>
        <xsl:variable name="m" select="input mod 100"/>

        <xsl:variable name="h12" select="round(($h + 11) mod 12 + 1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="am.pm" select="substring('AMPM', 1 + 2*($h > 11), 2)"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$h12"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '00')"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$am.pm"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>2:35 PM</output>
```